# Migrate 'react-router' into 'react-router-dom' (v4)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am learning React Routing and I am watching this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iAG6h9ff5s

Its 2016 tutorial so I suppose something changed because 'react-router' not working anymore and I am supposed to use 'react-router-dom'.

I found that I must uninstall 'history' and 'react-router' and use 'react-router-dom' instead, but It not working as expected when I change it.

**How to edit this to make it working with 'react-router-dom'?**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from "react-router";

import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
import Archives from "./pages/Archives";
import Featured from "./pages/Featured";
import Settings from "./pages/Settings";

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
            <IndexRoute component={Featured}></IndexRoute>
            <Route path="archives" component={Archives}></Route>
            <Route path="settings" component={Settings}></Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    app);
```

**My edit:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
import Archives from "./pages/Archives";
import Featured from "./pages/Featured";
import Settings from "./pages/Settings";

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
            <Route path="/featured" component={Featured}/>
            <Route path="/archives" component={Archives}/>
            <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    app);
```

Also pushState not working...
**Layout.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
    navigate() {
        this.props.history.pushState(null, "/");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <button onClick={this.navigate.bind(this)}>Featured</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I click to Link url change, but content is not loaded... Also when I access url I get "Cannot GET" error

Comment: You can look at [one of the examples in the documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic).

Comment: I watched this, but I have problems with Layout and his childs... Its not working...

Comment: Where is you link? Which component?

Comment: @devserkan Added on main post

Comment: Sorry, I can't see the `Link` again. Just let me understand your logic. What will be in your `Layout` component?

Comment: I just need to change code from tutorial to work in route v4. Or everyone still using old router???

Comment: Of course not, you can easily convert your code. But I just want to understand how your Layout look like. By the way, I never used the old version, so I can easily understand the new one but the old one is a little bit weird for me :) I will try to provide an answer, maybe we can continue from there.

Comment: I think its better to watch part of video where he showing it, but if u want I can try to explain it.. I need layout with menu links (one by onclick event) and dynamically changable pages inside layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After watching the video, you probably want something like this. At first this would not be so easy to understand but after seeing a few of them you digest it. First you render your `Layout` with one `Route`. Then in this top route, you use other `Route`s to setup your components.

We usually use `exact` props for a top root like `/`. If you don't setup your app like that, for example all your routes is in your top `Router` config, then to use a route something like `/featured` we must have `exact` prop. If we don't use it `Router` always hit `/` path and we always see the top level component.

But, in your situation, you want other components to be routed in your top level component. So, we drop `exact` prop here.

Also you can use `push` to change history.

**Update**

After think about the navigation button named "Featured", I think you want the `Featured` component rendered as default one here. When hit the button again you will come back to `Featured` one. I've changed the code according to that. In this version, we add a `/` route in the `Layout` and point it to `Featured`. So, when we come here it is rendered. But, we use `exact` prop here since we also want routes like "/featured", "/archives" and "/settings".

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  navigate = () => this.props.history.push("/");

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <Link to="/featured">Featured</Link>
        <Link to="/archives">Archives</Link>
        <Link to="/settings">Settings</Link>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.navigate}>Featured</button>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Featured} />
        <Route path="/featured" component={Featured} />
        <Route path="/archives" component={Archives} />
        <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
        <div>
        Some other info.
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const app = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Layout} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  app);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works as expected. So main difference between old v3 and new v4 is that u must place your Routes inside Layout instead placing them as childs of parent Route. Right?

Comment: You are welcome. Probably yes, but I'm not sure since I haven't use the old version at all. I'm this new :) But, as you explained we don't use any children and IndexRoute at all. We place our Routes in the layout and do the routing again there.